# Invalid date when parsing with locale it

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I need to parse a date in the "it" locale with momentjs, and I'm doing this

```
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/it';

moment.locale("it");
let d = "20/12/2018"; // 20 dec 2018
let mm = moment(d);
console.log(mm.format("DD MM YYYY"));
```

What I get is "invalid date" and I don't understand why. Can you help me?

Using the "en" locale (with the date written as 12/20/2018) all is ok

Comment: You need to tell _Moment_ what format you're feeding it. `let mm = moment(d, "DD/MM/YYYY");`

Comment: And if I don't know the format? The format depends on the locale, and I don't know what locale the user will be using

Comment: Is this part of a form to be filled by a user? If so, I don't know of any website that does not tell the user `Please enter the date in this format: ...` or uses a calendar widget so that the user does not even have to think about it. **Edit**: I'm not judging, I'm just asking

Comment: Yes the date comes from a form, but I let the user enter the date in the current browser locale. And then I thought I could parse it using the browser locale the same with moment, but from what you say this is not possible.

Comment: do not rely over their locale for storing the date, but format it using their locale when you are displaying it. You can instead store it in a single way (standard format, ms, etc...)

Comment: I'm not saying this is impossible. It probably is possible. I just don't know how, but I'm sure someone will :)

Comment: "*And if I don't know the format*" then how do you expect a parser to know?

Comment: @RobG the parser should know the format because it related to the locale

Comment: @quirimmo I store the date in the millis format, but I'd like to let the user enter the date in his own locale even if the site is in english. The problem is then parsing the date in the current browser locale, and I thought moment.locale was done to solve problems like this, but it doesn't seem so

Comment: The user doesn't necessarily conform to the format suggested by browser or system settings. Most browsers leverage system settings, I can't set different settings for my browser and system.

Comment: @RobG In my case the user conforms to the user locale set in the browser because I have a date picker and set its locale to be the one of the browser...

Comment: @cdarwin so why you don't read back the locale and use the same format you use for date picker in order to create your date with moment?

Comment: @quirimmo... you are right, I was going to do this at this point, but I thought that Momentjs could do this automatically

Comment: Some browsers allow setting a language, I don't know any that allow setting different regional settings to the host system. The point is that date formatting for input and output in general is not necessarily dependent on those settings. For example, The Daily Mail, a British newspaper, writes the date on the front page as "Thursday, December 27, 2018". The Times on its web site uses "27 December 2018". Both are very British.

Comment: @RobG maybe I haven't understood what you are saying, but my Firefox and Chrome allow me to set the locale in an independent way from the operating system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below snippet will accomplish what you want. It takes moment's date format for a given local and passes it to the constructor when creating a moment.

With that said, the comments above raise a lot of good points and this is not a reliable way to be handling dates.

For example, if someone in Italy entered a date string in the en `MM/DD/YYYY` format this would break

```
let localeFormat = moment.localeData('it').longDateFormat('L');
console.log(localeFormat) // DD/MM/YYYY

let d = "20/12/2018"; // 20 dec 2018
let mm = moment(d, localeFormat);
console.log(mm.format("DD MM YYYY"));
```

Comment: this is what I thought Moment could do